# Can I get (Microsoft Web.Helper) Facebook.Helper methods to a MVC controller?

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have installed Facebook.Helper for MVC 3 and this includes a lot of useful methods, but in a Razor view. So my question is, can I access these methods from a controller or any class at all, or do I have to implement these methods by myself?

TIA

Comment: Which methods in particular are you interested in calling from your server side code and most importantly to achieve what?

Comment: I'm most interested in methods like "IsFacebookUserAuthenticated" and "GetFacebookUserProfile". I simply want to use these methods to determine if an user has access or not, or to bind users information to server-side calls or models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best solution, but I copied all static methods and properties under "@functions { }" in file "/App_Code/Facebook.cshtml" and simply created a new static helper class.