# Why no 'Facebook' class in Microsoft.Web.Helpers?

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

I've downloaded Microsoft.Web.Helpers from NuGet to use in a MVC 3 (**no WebMatrix**!!!) project.
Contrary to many tutorials (like this: http://midnightprogrammer.net/post/Working-With-Microsoft-Web-Helpers-In-MVC-3-Razor-View.aspx and http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2010/11/07/using-asp-net-web-pages-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx) I don't have a `@Facebook.Like`, no Facebook class at all.

Can it be some WebMatrix specific thing? Is there a way to get *just the helpers*?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I get (Microsoft Web.Helper) Facebook.Helper methods to a MVC controller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511115/can-i-get-microsoft-web-helper-facebook-helper-methods-to-a-mvc-controller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get version 1.15

You'll have the @Facebook

Answer (score 0):

It's Facebook.LikeButton instead of Facebook.Like. Also make sure you have this on top,

```
@using Microsoft.Web.Helpers
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it with NuGet:

```
PM> Install-Package Facebook.Helper
```